# Can I extend list in Python with prepend elements instead of append?

Tags: python, list, append, prepend

I can perform

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
a.extend(b)
# a is now [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Is there way to perform an action for extending list and adding new items to the beginning of the list?

Like this

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
a.someaction(b)
# a is now [4,5,6,1,2,3]
```

I use version 2.7.5, if it is important.

Comment: Why can't you do `b.extend(a)`?

Comment: @iCodez: sometimes `a` is called `very_important` and `b` is called `aux`. You may want to keep the former and forget about the latter.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can assign to a slice:

```
a[:0] = b
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> a[:0] = b
>>> a
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Essentially, `list.extend()` is an assignment to the `list[len(list):]` slice.

You can 'insert' another list at any position, just address the empty slice at that location:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> a[1:1] = b
>>> a
[1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Sadly, a[-1:] doesn't work (for obvious reasons).  It would be so nice to have symmetry, but alas…

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard: There absolutely is symmetry, but `-1` is not the end of the list, it is the last element. `a[-1:]` is symmetrical with `a[:1]` at the start of the list, both contain 1 element. This is why I explicitly mention `len(list)` in my answer.

Answer (score 17):

This is what you need ;-)

```
a = b + a
```

Comment: u'll end up adding the corresponding array elements.

Comment: @magarwal Only if you are using numpy.

Comment: not if you need to modify `a`, try this: `>>> a is b+a` (`b+a` is neither `b` nor `a`, but a completely new object) ;)

Comment: Sometimes, you need to preserve a; e.g. if it is a memory reference in another list. This solution won't work in this case

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects):

```
import collections
a = collections.deque([1, 2, 3])
b = [4, 5, 6]
a.extendleft(b[::-1])
```

Comment: This is the best way if you don't need to be able to access arbitrary elements.  insert and adding lists tends to yield quadratic algorithms, where linear is possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you need fast operations *and* you need to be able to access arbitrary elements, try a treap or red-black tree.

```
>>> import treap as treap_mod
>>> treap = treap_mod.treap()
>>> for i in range(100000):
...    treap[i] = i
...
>>> treap[treap.find_min() - 1] = -1
>>> treap[100]
100
```

Most operations on treaps and red-black trees can be done in O(log(n)).  Treaps are purportedly faster on average, but red-black trees give a lower variance in operation times.